"Bitrate" function in udp out don't working if more than 1.35 Mbps
"Bitrate" function in udp out don't working if more than 1.35 Mbps on Windows with differents versions of ffmpeg.
I see similar question on Internet without solution ex: with option -Muxate 6Mbps :
"I have problem with ffmpeg in Windows. "Bitrate" function in udp out don't
work correctly. I can set any bitrate, it will be no more than 1.35 Mbps.
For example:  "udp://127.0.0.1:1234?pkt_size=1316&bitrate=6000000"
In Linux it work correctly, bitrate of stream is in accordance with set.
Has anyone experienced this?"
I try setting/increasing burst_bits without modification.
Need this function for DVB transmition experimentation.

Try adding -re as your first argument.

It's not a problem of real time or frame rate.
This fonction work properly with bitrate < 1350kbs
With differents computer or ffmpeg 5 or 6 or 7 the flow is always limited at 1350kbs on windows.
Example:
"-f mpegts -muxrate 2000000 udp://192.168.0.30&bitrate=2000000&overrun_nonfatal=1&fifo_size=262140&buffer_size=262140"
